# C# if statement not being excuted unity

Tags: c#, unityscript

Im working on a shop where user can increase the damage of his weapon when he clicks on a button the current damage is displayed along with his money which is stored as "score" in playerprefs  in the editor i ave set my money or "score" to be 80 i want it to cost 45 money everytime user wants to increase damage by 5 this is my script but for some reason its not working

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IncreaseDamage : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private int damage;
    private int math;
    private float money;
    private float math2;

    void Update()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");
    }

    public void increaseDamage()
    {
        if(money >= 45)
        {
            damage = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("damage");
            math = damage + 5;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("damage",math);
            math2 = money - 45;
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score",math2);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: i have made scripts which test the button and it works fine it stopped working once i added the if statement

other important scripts

This gets the players current damage it is attached to a UIText

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GetPlayerDamage : MonoBehaviour {
 Text text;
 private int damage;
 
 void Awake(){
  text = GetComponent <Text> ();
 }
 
 void Update(){
  damage = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("damage");
  text.text = "Damage: " + damage;
 }
}
```

this manages the score or money(same thing)

```html
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int score;


    Text text;


    void Awake ()
    {
        text = GetComponent <Text> ();
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        text.text = "Score: " + score;
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
    }
}
```

this displays the money in a text to the user

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class MoneyManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int score;
 



    Text text;


    void Awake ()
    {
        text = GetComponent <Text> ();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
  
        text.text = "Money: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
  

    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt you GetInt on score before you calculate math2?

Comment: If `money` is less than 45, `IncreaseDamage` will do nothing because the `if` condition will fail.....

Comment: where do you set money? note that default value is 0. so i guess you dont set money.

Comment: I'm going to assume you need a `money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");` before your if statement.

Comment: score is set as a float in another script and will not convert so it has to be int and also thats the point Tim they need at least 45

Comment: money is handled in another script its not the issue ive tested that

Comment: Why don't you show all relevant code that pertains to the issue that you are having ..whee do you even call `increaseDamage()` also make an else code block if the condition is not met and even more important.. use the `debugger`

Comment: money is handled in another script. where? i see that `private float money;` cant be accessed outside of this class. make sure you are setting value to this field otherwise it remains 0.

Comment: updated with all relevant scripts

Comment: Where do you call `increaseDamage()`?

Comment: increaseDamage is called as a function onclick of the button

Comment: Why are you getting `money` in `Update` if your need is to use it in only `public void increaseDamage()`?? You can get it in `public void increaseDamage()` before your if check. There you can easily check by marking BreakPoints of logging the money at the time when that method is being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `money`.

Although there is not enough information given in the question I'm going to assume you need to pull the score before you calculate `if(money >= 45)` with something like `money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IncreaseDamage : MonoBehaviour {
     private int damage;
     private int math;
     private float money;
     private float math2;

     void Update(){
         money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");
     }

     public void increaseDamage(){
         money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");
         if(money >= 45){
             damage = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("damage");
             math = damage + 5;
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt("damage",math);
             math2 = money - 45;
             PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score",math2);
         }
     }
 }
```

EDIT: Or you could call `Update()` before calling `increaseDamage()` in your button

Comment: Not really sure what could be wrong without more information. Try changing `money = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");` to `money = 50;` to see if that makes `increaseDamage()` work. If it does work then it means your money isn't being stored in `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");` and you need to figure out where it is being stored. If it doesn't work then it's something else that is wrong that you haven't shown in the question yet.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue i was getting score as a float when i should have been getting it as an int

heres the updated(and correct) code

```C#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IncreaseDamage : MonoBehaviour {
    private int damage;
    private int math;
    private int money;
    private int math2;

    void Update(){
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
    }

    public void increaseDamage(){
        if(money >= 45){
            damage = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("damage");
            math = damage + 5;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("damage",math);
            math2 = money - 45;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",math2);
        }
    }
}
```